# Multiple Users Per Node Via JSON RPC

Tags: rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I have been looking at the JSON RPC Api for connecting to a Node. Can a node support multiple users connecting to it, all with individual wallets...? I've been looking at https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc and it indicates that is support for a session, but I'm not sure how to start a new session.

Does anyone have any examples of doing this...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "node" is the monerod daemon. It can support arbitrarily many wallets connecting to it concurrently. A wallet generally supports only one user at a time.